Can we transform verbs from one form to another?
The complex transitive form "verb + direct object + to+ v¹":

It takes two hours to get to the airport.

Now can we use the simple form "verb + Direct object".
For example,

It takes two hours.

If it is possible, then can we use this form also with other verbs?
I am so confused about these.


It takes two hours to get to the airport uses 'anticipatory it'.

The sentence is of the form

It is tough to solve this problem.

This is the classic example of a transformation known as tough-movement. The sentence

This problem is tough to solve.

is in the prototypical format.

To get to the airport takes two hours.

is not very natural-sounding, but is a grammatical paraphrase without 'anticipatory it'.
Sentences exhibiting tough-movement are often deleted when the deletion is obvious (perhaps from prior context):

It takes two hours [to get to the airport]

It is tough [to solve this problem; 'This problem is tough' is another possibile undeleted form, but has the same meaning anyway].

It's easy [to make Jill smile].

It will take a long time [to build this wall].

It's no joke [cooking for twenty].


So the to-infinitival (or ing-clause) may be dropped from such sentences, if the meaning is still clear.

And can we say "he goes/went" instead of saying "he goes/went there"?

There are tricky restrictions. Permitted (though not the only) responses: "Has he gone to the airport yet?" ... "Yes, he's gone." /  "Does John still go to watch United?" ... "Yes, he goes." //// BUT "Does John go home via the pub after work?" ...*"Yes, he goes." We'd have to use do-support in this case.  ////// Argumentation (what arguments ... subjects, objects, complements, directionals etc are optional / obligatory and when) is a mammoth study. Aarts has famously titled a book 'English Syntax and Argumentation'.

See also keep discussing vs keep discussing it. The general 'object deletion' has been discussed before ('We ate tea' vs 'We ate'; 'John plays chess/the piano' vs 'John plays' .... Different verbs have different requirements, but are often flexible. Strictly intransitive verbs are fairly rare, for instance.

I understand. Thank you so much...

You have used the wrong form in your example. It should be either It takes two hours or I take two hours. Either is perfectly valid; in each there is a complement elided, so it must be understood from context. If someone approached me and said, “It takes two hours” or “I take two hours,” my response would be, “To do what?”

But in OLED, there has the verb form ' verb+sth+to do sth. Isn't "to do sth" a non-core complement?

I don’t understand why you have reported that. An utterance like I hate my evening commute. It takes two hours is perfectly understandable and entirely idiomatic. Here, the elided “to do sth.”   is to make my evening commute.

Cause cgel says those are non-core complements.

Like, take + sth + to fo sth, take sb/sth + adv/prep., attention to sth

Yes, to make my evening commute is indeed a non-core complement. That’s why It takes two hours is a syntactically valid sentence. But whether it is pragmatically understandable is another matter. That depends on context.

It’s analogous to the situation in which my granddaughter approaches me and says, “I ate it.” Even though her sentence is fine syntactically, I may or may not know the antecedent of it. So if I don’t, and fearing the worst, I’d reply, “Ate what?”

And what about specified prepositions after Adjective? Are those necessary or not?

What prepositions? What adjectives? Context is always critically important.

Like, afraid of, ashamed of..

What about afraid of and ashamed of? What are you asking?

For example, I am afraid of him. I am ashamed of this situation.  From here can we remove Prepositional phrases of him and of this situation?

Yes, when the object of our fear or shame is either understood or unimportant, we can say simply, “I am afraid” or “I am ashamed.”

And Thank you so much for your help.
